# Iniciar servidor XAMPP desde CMD

Tags: xampp, cmd, línea-de-comandos

Existe algún modo de iniciar/detener XAMPP (servidor apache y mySql) usando la terminal en Windows 10?

PD: La ruta donde está el programa es la que se crea por defecto al instalarlo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si, puedes usar los siguientes comandos para ello:

Inciar ambos servicios

> **\xampp\xampp_start.exe**

Detener los servicios de MySql y Apache

> **\xampp\xampp_stop.exe**

Iniciar Apache

> **\xampp\apache_start.bat**

Apagar Apache

> **\xampp\apache_stop.bat**

Iniciar MySql

> **\xampp\mysql_start.bat**

Detener MySql

> **\xampp\mysql_stop.bat**

Solo tienes que iniciar el CMD de windows y pegar tal cual está en las notas.